# Convergence sensitive to choice of baseline category?

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

While running a simulation in R, I noticed that in fitting one particular model, R spits out a warning message, but if I simply change the baseline category in the response variable, it converges without complaining. The results produced do not differ appreciably, except that one value in the random effect correlation matrix is changed. I am curious why this occurs, and whether it suggests something interesting about the data set (the response variable is binary valued, and the explanatory variables are continuous-valued).

```
> library(lme4)
> fit1.MS.eE <- glmer(label ~ zSpec * zF1 + zF2 + (1 + zSpec + zF1 + zF2 | part), data = MSall.eE, family = binomial())
Warning message:
In mer_finalize(ans) : singular convergence (7)
> MSall.eE$label <- relevel(MSall.eE$label, "e")
> fit1.MS.eE <- glmer(label ~ zSpec * zF1 + zF2 + (1 + zSpec + zF1 + zF2 | part), data = MSall.eE, family = binomial())
>(no warning message)
```

I have uploaded [the data set](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~lovegren/sample.R) referred to in the code for interested persons.

Comment: This question seems to be only about how something about R works, and not any related statistical content (although that doesn't make it a bad question). As such, it is better asked (& probably answered) on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @gung Thanks, can it be migrated?

Comment: This question looks like it has statistical content to me: after all, with the same data and similar procedures, it is plausible that *any* statistical package might encounter the same problem.  It might help if you could post a sample dataset (or a means to simulate a dataset) so that interested readers could reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @whuber I've uploaded a data set which can be used to reproduce the result.

Comment: Thanks.  I get a `false convergence (8)` warning for *both* models (R 2.11.1, Win 7/64).

Comment: @whuber That is curious, I just checked again and I still have the same `singular convergence (7)` error when "E" is the baseline. I am running R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows" on Ubuntu, and used the `arm` package (ver. 1.5-03) to access the `glmer` function.

Comment: Maybe there's a clue there: in the absence of any information, I located `lme4::glmer` for my test (and inserted a `library` command in your post to be explicit about that--you might want to change that). Something is awry with the model: that much is clear. I suspect the difference due to reordering the levels may be a red herring (reflecting some underlying numerical instability) and perhaps you should focus on diagnosing the model itself to find the cause of that instability.

Comment: @whuber I just installed R 2.15.1 on my Windows Vista/32 computer, and got the same `false convergence (8)` warning as you report. Anyway, playing with other models based on the same data set it looks like the issue is that there are 3 groups for the purpose of fitting random slopes (similar data sets with 4 and 5 groups converged fine), so I suppose that my question is going to end up as an academic issue.